# Is there a JProfiler equivalent for .NET?

Tags: .net, jprofiler

I am used to profiling Java programs using Jprofiler which can give you a CPU Percentage breakdown for each class and method.  Is there a similar tool for .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jet brains dottrace.
[link](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a simple and free profiler, have a look at the [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler).

Answer (score 2):

Redgate [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm). You might want to look at [CLR profiler too](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a362781c-3870-43be-8926-862b40aa0cd0&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

[Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/index.jsp) has a .NET profiler as well. But its trial version

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45744/code-profiling-in-visual-studio-2005) "Code Profiling in Visual Studio 2005". And to be free is very nice. I haven't used Ants nor jetbrains to compare.